# dumping array vertical direction in excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When I'm tring to dump an array `Dim A (1 To 3) As String` to vertical range of cells `A1:A3`, the first cell of the array is duplicated for all the range.

For example, assuming  `A(1) = "a" ,  A(2) = "b"  , A(3) = "c"` so the result is `a` in all the `A1:A3` range.

The code is `Range("A1:A3").Value = A`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Sub Tester()

Dim a(1 To 3)

    a(1) = "a"
    a(2) = "b"
    a(3) = "c"

    Range("A1:A3").Value = a  'all "a"

    Range("A1:C1").Value = a  'works, because left-to-right is the default

    Range("A1:A3").Value = Application.Transpose(a) 'works


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

My usual practice is to Redim the Array same dimension as the range Object

For Range "A1:A3" is a 3*1 2D array

```
Sub testing()
    Dim a()
    ' a(1 to rowCount, 1 to columnCount)
    ReDim a(1 To 3, 1 To 1)
    a(1, 1) = "A"
    a(2, 1) = "B"
    a(3, 1) = "C"
    Range("A1:A3").Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: Why `ReDim` - which is actually a longer process than you have shown as the 1D Array already exists - ie you would need to loop through the 1D array to make a new 2D one. Just dump the 1D array directly with `Transpose` as Tim suggest

Answer (score -2):

This function transposes 1D array to a "vertical" 2D array, which can then be assigned to `Range.Value`. `Application.Transpose` is not suitable for big arrays (14464 cells on my Excel 2013 x64).

```
Private Function array_as_2d(arr)
    'Convert 1D array into 2D array
    Dim tmp
    tmp = Array()
    lb = LBound(tmp)
    ReDim tmp(LBound(arr) To UBound(arr), lb)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        tmp(i, lb) = arr(i)
    Next i
    array_as_2d = tmp
End Function

Sub test_assign()
    Dim a(0 To 2)
    a(0) = 7
    a(1) = 8
    a(2) = 9
    Range("A1:A3") = array_as_2d(a)
    Range("B1:B3") = array_as_2d(Array(1, 2, 3))
End Sub
```